# Spring boot 2 migration from Spring boot 1.5 issue with redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, redis

i need to change Redis code so it will work with new SpringBoot 2.0.3, currently when starting Tomcat 9.0.12 (not starting SpringBoot as Jar - cause of business needs) i get following error:

```
 ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method vehicleHistoryCacheManager in somePath.config.UfCacheConfig 
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' in 'JedisConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean 
    (types: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) 
    beans of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' redisConnectionFactory
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' in 'LettuceConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean 
    (types: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) 
    found beans of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' redisConnectionFactory


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' in your configuration.

19-Oct-2018 13:43:22.142 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/motoPolicy]]
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'technicalController' 
defined in file [somePath\TecController.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ufCacheServiceImpl' 
defined in URL [jar:file:/someName.jar!/somePath/UfCacheServiceImpl.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' defined in class path resource 
[somePath/config/UfCacheConfig.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=vehicleTemplate)}
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ufgCacheServiceImpl' 
defined in URL [jar:file:/uf.jar!/somePath/UfgCacheServiceImpl.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' defined in class path resource
 [somePath/config/UfCacheConfig.class]: 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' parameter 0; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
 No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: 
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=vehicleTemplate)}
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' defined in class path resource 
[somePath/config/UfCacheConfig.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vehicleHistoryCacheManager' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=vehicleTemplate)}
(...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=vehicleTemplate)}
(...)

19-Oct-2018 13:43:22.162 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method manageApp
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
 Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/motoPolicy]]
(...)
[2018-10-19 01:43:22,176] Artifact motoPolicy-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
(...)

19-Oct-2018 13:43:22.162 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
 javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/motoPolicy]]
(...)
```

My dependecies about Redis in pom are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's redis config:

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${ufg.redis.host}") // 127.0.0.1
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${ufg.redis.port}") // 6379
    private int port;

    @Bean
    LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(hostName);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper redisObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Here's configuration class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class UfCacheConfig {
    public static final String VEHICLE_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER = "vehicleHistoryCacheManager";
    public static final String VEHICLE_HISTORY_CACHE = "vehicleHistoryCache";
    public static final String VEHICLE_GENERATOR_NAME = "vehicleKeyGenerator";
    public static final String PERSON_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER = "personHistoryCacheManager";
    public static final String PERSON_HISTORY_CACHE = "personHistoryCache";
    public static final String PERSON_GENERATOR_NAME = "personKeyGenerator";

    @Value("${ufg.cache.expiration.validity.minutes}")
    private int expirationValidityMinutes;

    @Bean(value ="vehicleTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, GetVehicleInsuranceHistoryResponse> vehicleTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                                                                     @Qualifier("redisObjectMapper") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        RedisTemplate<String, GetVehicleInsuranceHistoryResponse> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = VEHICLE_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER)
    public CacheManager vehicleHistoryCacheManager(@Qualifier("vehicleTemplate") RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Duration expiration = Duration.ofSeconds(expirationValidityMinutes * 60);
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(expiration)).build();
    }

    @Bean(value ="personTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, GetPersonInsuranceHistoryResponse> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                                                                  @Qualifier("redisObjectMapper") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        RedisTemplate<String, GetPersonInsuranceHistoryResponse> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = PERSON_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER)
    public CacheManager personHistoryCacheManager(@Qualifier("personTemplate") RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Duration expiration = Duration.ofSeconds(expirationValidityMinutes * 60);
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(expiration)).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = VEHICLE_GENERATOR_NAME)
    public KeyGenerator vehicleKeyGenerator() {
        return (o, method, objects) -> new VehicleKeyGenerator((GetVehicleInsuranceHistoryRequest) objects[0]).generate();
    }

    @Bean(name = PERSON_GENERATOR_NAME)
    public KeyGenerator personKeyGenerator() {
        return (o, method, objects) -> new PersonKeyGenerator((GetPersonInsuranceHistoryRequest) objects[0]).generate();
    }

    private static <T> RedisTemplate<String, T> createTemplate(Class<T> clazz, RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<T> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(clazz);
        serializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(serializer);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Here's service class that is mentioned in the stack trace:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UfCacheServiceImpl implements UfCacheService {
    private CacheManager vehicleCacheManager;
    private CacheManager personCacheManager;

    @Autowired
    public UfCacheServiceImpl(@Qualifier(VEHICLE_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER) CacheManager vehicleCacheManager,
                               @Qualifier(PERSON_HISTORY_CACHE_MANAGER) CacheManager personCacheManager) {
        this.vehicleCacheManager = vehicleCacheManager;
        this.personCacheManager = personCacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        log.info("Clearing ufg cache");
        vehicleCacheManager.getCache(VEHICLE_HISTORY_CACHE).clear();
        personCacheManager.getCache(PERSON_HISTORY_CACHE).clear();
    }
}
```

As you can see i used stuff like but redis does not work:

```
@Bean(value ="vehicleTemplate")
@Qualifier("vehicleTemplate")
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding `Boris` answer:
The only stuff that I can find (in whole project) with phrases like `jedis` or `Jedis` are pom dependencies. When i remove them the output changes to:

```
Parameter 0 of method vehicleHistoryCacheManager in somePackages.config.UfCacheConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis'
- Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' in 'LettuceConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory; 
SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' redisConnectionFactory
```

I could not find such a thing like `JedisConnectionConfiguration` to delete it.

After commenting the dependencies in pom I could not find phrase `jedis` in External Libraries.

I saw that in version with`spring-boot-starter-parent` (in the main parent pom) in `External Libraries` i have only `spring-data-redis` 2.0.8.

Comment: When specifying, for example, `<version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>` you override version defined in DependencyManagement. Remove explicit version declarations.

Comment: @Boris sometimes i must define version cause i get error in tomcat. When i removed version from this four dependencies i get the same error. Also i see that i have two versions of `spring-data-redis` (in `External Libraries`) one is `2.0.8`, second is `1.8.14`.

Comment: @Boris Now when i try to do `mvn clean install` i get following error:
`[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar is missing. @ line 161, column 21`
This is no good to delete all `version`.

Comment: It means your POM file is missing the `spring-boot-starter-parent` `<parent>` block which allows to inherit defaults from Spring Boot. Can you double check and maybe updated the POM snippet? See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven) for more details.

Comment: @Boris I'm sorry this poms are missing `spring-boot-starter-parent` i went from childs pom's to main parent. I do not see anywhere `spring-boot-starter-parent` do i really need it? The project worked before. The `parent` property refers to another pom usually.

Comment: Quote from [Spring Boot in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-boot-in-action) book, p.37: "...take caution when overriding the dependencies that are pulled in transitively by Spring Boot starter dependencies. Although different versions may work fine, there’s a great amount of comfort that can be taken knowing that the versions chosen by the starters have been tested to play well together. You should only override these transitive dependencies under special circumstances (such as a bug fix in a newer version)."

Comment: @Boris awesome comment. I deleted these versions of pom from the question dependencies. Then added to main parent pom as `parent` the `spring-boot-starter-parent` but i've got still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182145/discussion-between-boris-and-yami).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have placed [@ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) annotation that only matches when no beans of `RedisConnectionFactory` classes are already contained in the BeanFactory. Looking at the log we can see that you are trying to configure both the Lettuce and Jedis client libraries:

```
- Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' in 'JedisConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean
- Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' in 'LettuceConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean
```

But you should be using only one at a time.
Delete `JedisConnectionConfiguration` and remove the `jedis` dependency if you want to use Lettuce and vice versa.

However I recommend to use a Redis Starter instead:

**1.** Add `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**2.** Remove `jedis` and `spring-data-redis` maven dependencies

**3.** Remove @Qualifier annotations since you don't need more control over the [autowiring selection process](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

**4.** Set the connection factory by using [setConnectionFactory()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisAccessor.html#setConnectionFactory-org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory-)

```java
redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
```

**5.** Use Redis Starter offered basic auto-configuration

Remove `redisConnectionFactory()` method.

Inject an auto-configured `RedisConnectionFactory` or `RedisTemplate` instance as you would any other Spring Bean in order to connect to Redis.

**6.** Use Spring Boot Redis properties

Spring Boot uses these default Redis properties which you can overwrite in the properties file:

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-redis) for more details.

Comment: I think the issue is around `@Qualifier("personTemplate")` and `@Qualifier("vehicleTemplate")` earlier i had templates, but now design changed and i do not how i can have two templates, the method `personHistoryCacheManager` now takes `redisConnectionFactory` as argument instead of `RedisTemplate` as it used to. How can i make this two templates work again? Earlier this: `RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(vehicleTemplate);` worked. `vehicleTemplate` was `RedisTemplate`.

Comment: Ok it is actually set by `redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);`

Comment: I hope that i dont miss logic that i had earlier by this code: `RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(personTemplate);`

Comment: @yami have you removed `spring-data-redis` as well?

Comment: No, should I ? The main issue was about this `@Qualifier` things (i removed them), i give U up vote, but no accept - cause it is not full answer. Now i do not get this error.

Comment: Yes, you should if you're using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`. Thanks, is anything missing still?

Comment: i mean that your answer does not contain the info I gave U in the comments - for example that i should remove `@Qualifier` to make it work.

Comment: Ok, by the way, you can write your own full answer. This is accepted in StackOverflow. Or I can update mine with your info.

Comment: i know that i can make my own answer - but i am very thankful for you and i sugest that U update answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182265/discussion-between-boris-and-yami).